# VS Code producing errors after setting it up also as an Arduino IDE

Tags: c, json, gcc, visual-studio-code, arduino

I've installed the Arduino extension for VS Code and added arduino.path to match ("/$HOME/Desktop/arduino-1.8.13/). Although the code compiles and executes fine, VS Code produces 2 errors:

#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/home/hkm/Desktop/arduino-1.8.13/Arduino/led_game/led_game.ino).

cannot open source file "avr/pgmspace.h" (dependency of "/home/hkm/Desktop/arduino-1.8.13/Arduino/led_game/led_game.ino")

Not sure what I need to do in order to fix it, Here is my c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "/home/hkm/Desktop/arduino-1.8.13/tools/**",
            "/home/hkm/Desktop/arduino-1.8.13/hardware/arduino/avr/**"
        ],
        "forcedInclude": [
            "/home/hkm/Desktop/arduino-1.8.13/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Arduino.h"
        ],
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "cStandard": "gnu18",
        "cppStandard": "gnu++14"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

The error occurs for .ino and .c files (which are basically the only things I work on VS Code).
GCC is my preferred compiler.

All help is appreciated thanks.